# Query to check latest modifications in entire database (fields and structure)

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, is there a query that shows me the latest modifications in both data (every table) and tables structures?

I need to check if in a database happens some modifications in recent days (data and structure).
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the safest way is to analize transaction log.. Severa tools can do that, but onestly I never used them.

Comment: `select * from sys.objects where modify_date > @yourDate` will get you changes in structure but not data rows.

Comment: No way to track data modifications also?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly, I don't know relible way to track data and structure changes out of the box without additional efforts (like creating DDL triggers, CDC, temporal tables).

With certain assumptions, you can query to the `sys.objects` table by `modify_date` field (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16; see @Charlieface comment) to track structure changes. But keep in mind `modify_date` also changes when a clustered index created or rebuilt. Is it the changes you would like to consider along the others?

To track data changes, you can check index usage statistics in the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` table (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Each data change (insert / update / delete) will update the usage statistics of particular table, but there also some limitations exists (e.g., these statistics are reset every time server is started).

Thus, you can check the changes for some date with the next query, but you should be aware of the existsing limitations:

```
DECLARE @Date date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())

IF (
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects AS o WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND o.modify_date > @Date)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS s JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.object_id = s.object_id AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 WHERE s.last_user_update > @Date)
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Changed'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No changes'
END
```

It is worth noting that this query doesn't respect changes in system tables (`sys.objects.is_ms_shipped = 0`) and changes made by internaly generated queries (the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.last_system_update` field is omitted).